# Android: Populate TextView with row results (sqlite) from itemOnSelected Spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite, textview, spinner

I would like to use a spinner as a menu to be able to select the name of a workout, upon selection the `TextView`s (x4) will be populated with the exercises relevant to that name.
Currently the Spinner loads the workout names and have got as far as loading the first workout into each of the `TextView`'s `onCreation`.

There are no errors when the app is launched, but the other rows don't load into the TextViews when the the new workout name is selected.. One can only assume I have made an error in the logic.

Question: If it is an error in the logic can someone identify it and point me in the direction please?

begin.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin);

    loadSpinnerData();
    refreshTextView();



}

   public void loadTextView(){
    DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> exercises = dataHelper.getExercises();



          ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.exercise1)).setText(exercises.get(0));

          ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.exercise2)).setText(exercises.get(1));

          ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.exercise3)).setText(exercises.get(2));

          ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.exercise4)).setText(exercises.get(3));


  }
    public void refreshTextView(){
    Spinner databaseR = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.databaseR);
    databaseR.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            loadTextView();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

DataHelper.java

```
  public  String Create_ex="CREATE TABLE ExerciserEasy"
        + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Workout VARCHAR, ExerciseOne VARCHAR,"
        +"ExerciseTwo VARCHAR, ExerciseThree VARCHAR, ExerciseFour VARCHAR );"

   public ArrayList<String> getExercises(){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        String selectQuery = " Select * from " + Table_ex1;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                list.add(cursor.getString(4));
                list.add(cursor.getString(5));
                Log.d("HIITtimer", ""+cursor.getCount());

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {

        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();


    }
    return list;


}
```

Comment: Please show your Spinner onItemSelected code. You are always loading only the first 4 exercises into your textview.

Comment: Is your TextViews showing right data ? Is there any items in your spinner now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to pass the selected workout name to `loadTextView()` so you can pass it to `getExercises()`
and query the database based on that name, other code looks fine,

1- add parameter `workoutName` to `getExercises()`, and use it in `WHERE` clause

```
public ArrayList<String> getExercises(String workoutName){
    //codes ...
    String selectQuery = " Select * from " + Table_ex1 + " WHERE Workout ='" workoutName + "'";
    //codes ...
}
```

*Note: you may want to use `SQLiteDatabase#query()` instead of row query?*

2- add parameter `workoutName` to `loadTextView()`, and pass it to `getExercises()`:

```
public void loadTextView(String workoutName){
    //code ...
    ArrayList<String> exercises = dataHelper.getExercises(workoutName);
    //code ...
}
```

3- pass selected workout from spinner's `setOnItemSelectedListener()`:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    loadTextView(databaseR.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

now when item is selected, `loadTextView()` is called, telling the method which workout was selected, and query database to get the record related to that workout name.